# Наличие сертификата по Java

Tags: java

Является ли достаточным подтверждением квалификации наличие сертификата об успешной сдаче экзамена по Java при на найме нового разработчика на Java?

Comment: Подтверждением чего? Про какой именно сертификат речь? При найме нового разработчика куда?

Comment: в общем случае, сертификаты не имеют значения, если только об этом явно не прописано в вакансии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный вопрос не возможно дать однозначный ответ. Поскольку сертификат, диплом, медаль, орден выдаются организациями занимающимися этим делом. А признавать или нет дело хозяйское. Если вам именно вам этого достаточно то хорошо, а если этот сертификат не соответствует вашим ожиданиям то нет.

Во избежание проблем собственно и существует понятие как испытательный срок. Ведь никто не застрахован от мошенничества.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос ка к я понимаю  надо задавать к тому к то проводит  техническое собеседование кандидата на позицию разработчика. У меня на проекте так называемый  технический специалист проводивший собеседования  с кандидатами оказался очень низкого качества. Он  сразу "резал" тех кто был  сертифицирован.